# Get TFS information for locally mapped file or directory via WebApi

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-sdk

I want to use the `Teamfoundation.SourceControl.WebApi` to check for updates or local changes against our TFS Source Control.

I can gather information about changesets from an item which is committed TFS but I am not able to gather this information based on a local file path inside my mapped workspace.

Is it somehow possible without using the `ExtendedClient`?

I want something like this:

```
TfvcChangesetSearchCriteria tcsc = new TfvcChangesetSearchCriteria();
tcsc.ItemPath = @"c:\source\mappedtfs\MYPROJECT\src\MainWindow.cs";/*<--- localPath would be nice here*/                
List<TfvcChangesetRef> changerefs = tfvcHttpClient.GetChangesetsAsync("MYPROJECT", null, null, null, null, tcsc).Result;
```

Comment: Have you resolved the issue by Eddie's solution? any update?

Comment: Not exactly. As I mentioned, I want to avoid the usage of ExtendedClient assemblies. I understand, that a webapi does not interact with local files and folders. But why is it supported to commit changes via WebApi if this makes no sense?

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.Teamfoundation.SourceControl.WebApi` is a webapi which does not interact with local workspaces and files. If you want to get changesets with local items' path, use `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client` in the Client Library.

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleX
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri url = new Uri("https://tfsuri");
            TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(url);
            VersionControlServer vcs = ttpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            IEnumerable<Changeset> cses = vcs.QueryHistory("Path here could be local path or server path", RecursionType.Full);
            foreach (Changeset cs in cses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cs.ChangesetId);
                Console.WriteLine(cs.Comment);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eddie, that was what I've suspected: I must use the clientlibrary.